# Fluent UI Blazor Components - FluentProgress - Set progress bar height

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, fluent-ui

As the title suggests I would like to make the `FluentProgress` bar thicker.

```
<h4>Default</h4>
<div style="width: 300px; display: grid; grid-gap: 12px; grid-auto-flow: column;">
    <FluentProgress Min="0" Max="100" Value="75"></FluentProgress>
</div>
```

https://brave-cliff-0c0c93310.azurestaticapps.net/Progress

I can't find any parameter in documentation to achieve that however.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `fluent-progress` CSS the way to calculate height looks like this:

```
height: calc((var(--stroke-width) * 3) * 1px);
```

Therefore adding `style="--stroke-width: x;"` causes FluentProgress to be thicker. Example with `--stroke-width: 3`:

```
<FluentProgress Min="0" Max="100" Value="75" style="--stroke-width: 3;"></FluentProgress>
```

[image]

[image]